# Choosing a test for questionnaire analysis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I want to analyse the data from the following experiment setup:

Participants were divided into three groups, each group read a story and had to anwser a question by choosing option ***A*** or ***B***. The age, education and gender were also recorded.

Each group had approximately 50 participants.

I want to find out if there were *significant differences between the ratios of A/B in all three goups* (how people from different groups answeared). **What test(s) would be best to find that out?**

Cheers!

Comment: Are you interested in comparing all three groups to one another, adjusting for the variables you've mentioned?

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal

Comment: Have you thought of logistic regression?

Comment: Yes, but  how do I compare if there are meaningful differences between 3 samples? Do I build 3 models and compare coefficients?

Answer (score 2):

You can use logistic regression to do this.

Let the answer $A$ denote a positive outcome, and $B$ a negative outcome (in logistic regression, 1 and 0 respectively).  We can examine how group membership changes the probability of answering $A$ adjusting for age, education, and gender.

The model would be

$$  \operatorname{logit}(p) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \mbox{age} + \beta_2 \mbox{edu} + \beta_3 \mbox{gender} + \beta_4 \mbox{is in group 2} + \beta_5 \mbox{is in group3} $$

Here, the groups have been treated as a categorical variable, using group 1 as the reference group.  I suspect you might also want to make education a categorical variable, but I'm not sure how you coded that.

In this model, the reference group is group 1, and so the tests for coefficients 4 and 5 will tell you if there is a difference between groups 1 and 2 and groups 1 and 3.  If you're interested in differences between 2 and 3, you'd need to do an adjustment to the tests to account for multiple comparisons.  If you're using something like R, the `emmeans` package is helpful for this.

Answer (score 0):

The Chi-squared test will do the thing. If there are differences found, a post-hoc pairwise comparison will be required.